# Unable to run realm-cli on mac m1, return node:internal/child_process

Tags: mongodb, realm

When I try to run realm-cli I get node:internal/child_process everytime, no matter what i do.
I tried reinstalling, using different node version, previous mongodb-realm-cli version, same error.
I'm on new Mac M1, using zsh and nvm

```
$ realm-cli whoami
node:internal/child_process:413
    throw errnoException(err, 'spawn');
    ^

Error: spawn Unknown system error -86
    at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:413:11)
    at spawn (node:child_process:700:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v17.9.0/lib/node_modules/mongodb-realm-cli/wrapper.js:22:22)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1099:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  errno: -86,
  code: 'Unknown system error -86',
  syscall: 'spawn'
}

Node.js v17.9.0
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I am guessing you've got outdated versions. Do this `realm-cli --version` and ensure you have V2 or higher. You could have an API key issue as well. So step through the [Realm CLI Tutorial](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/tutorial/nodejs-cli/) and maybe even see the comments to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69035565/unable-to-install-realm-cli-mac). A -86 error is a streams pipe error which indicates one or more processes are not communicating with other processes.

Comment: thank you. My issue was that i did a mac transfer from old mac to new M1 which broke few things for me. I had to redo setup from scratch and it worked.